# What is the localName of this XML string?

Tags: java, android, sax

I was going to ask an entirely different question, but magically managed to solve that. So, a new problem.

So I'm working on an android app with SAX parser. I have an XML file that contains mostly

```
<content:encoded>bla bla bla</content:encoded>
```

And I know I can use localName encoded to get that one.

```
 @Override
 public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
   throws SAXException {

  if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(descriptionId))
  {
        if (isItem){descriptionList.add(buff.toString());}
  }
... etc etc
```

but then there's this:

```
<enclosure url="SOME URL" length="100623688" type="audio/mpeg"/>
```

And I want to extract SOME URL. Does anyone know how I would do that?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: "enclosure" is the element tag name and "url", "length" and "type" are attributes. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never developed for android, but if I understand you correctly, you need to read the attributes of that XML element.

In the startElement method of your SaxParser you'll have an argument "Attributes attrs" or something along those lines (at least this is what I remember from the Xerces SAX Parser).

That Attributes object contains the various... attributes of the element =) 
I think it's implemented over a Map, but you can debug that quickly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No need to try remembering. Just read the api doc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29

Comment: Perfect, this resolved to `descriptionList.add(attributes.getValue("url"));` working like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here SOME URL is the value of the attribute url which belongs to the enclosure tag.

Here is a sample take from

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/org.xml.sax/GetAttr.html

```
// Create a handler for SAX events
DefaultHandler handler = new MyHandler();

// Parse an XML file using SAX;
// The Quintessential Program to Parse an XML File Using SAX
parseXmlFile("infilename.xml", handler, true);

// This class listens for startElement SAX events
static class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    // This method is called when an element is encountered
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                             String qName, Attributes atts)  {
        // Get the number of attribute
        int length = atts.getLength();

        // Process each attribute
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            // Get names and values for each attribute
            String name = atts.getQName(i);
            String value = atts.getValue(i);

            // The following methods are valid only if the parser is namespace-aware

            // The uri of the attribute's namespace
            String nsUri = atts.getURI(i);

            // This is the name without the prefix
            String lName = atts.getLocalName(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I managed to find it in the startElement part. I feel stupid for not looking there. Thanks!